# Accessing public static class files from .ASPX file using Eval("") from gridView

Tags: asp.net, class, gridview, eval, invoke

Hi I am new to this system, please be gentle with me. The problem I am now having is the inability to call the class file from ASPX through Eval. The class file is located in "~/classes" folder. Please provide me with methods and ways to evade this error or even solve it thank you!! ^^

**Programming language** : C# 
**Problem found in** : .ASPX gridView
**Problem also found in** : EstateDBManager class file 
**Error Message** : DataBinding: 'DWAD_Project.classes.Volunteer' does not contain a property with the name 'EstateDBManager'. 
**Codes for partial gridView below** :

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estate Name" SortExpression="EstateId">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EstateDBManager.findEstate({0}).Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EstateDBManager.findEstate({0}).Name") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Codes for partial EstateDBManager Class file below:**

```
    namespace DWAD_Project.classes
    {
      public static class EstateDBManager
      {
        public static Estate findEstate(int ID)
        {
           // processes ...
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks for replies and helps!! ^^

**Answer to the problem**: 
**GridView** :

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estate Name" SortExpression="EstateId">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DWAD_Project.classes.EstateDBManager.findEstate(Eval("EstateId")).Name %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DWAD_Project.classes.EstateDBManager.findEstate(Eval("EstateId")).Name %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Class file** :

```
    namespace DWAD_Project.classes
    {
      public static class EstateDBManager
      {
        public static Estate findEstate(int ID)
        {
           // processes ...
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval is for properties of the data source. If you need just code don't use Eval

```
'<%# EstateDBManager.findEstate(Eval("EstateId")).Name %>'
```

You just have to convert the Eval result to the right type since it is object (e.g. (int)Eval("EstateId"))

Comment: EstateId from the datasource of the gridview

Comment: Hi, it gives me another error now T_T

    'The name 'EstateDBManager' does not exist in the current context.'

Comment: You need to specify the full namespace path or to add an import header which is the equivalent of "using" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx

Comment: ok '<%# DWAD_Project.classes.EstateDBManager.findEstate(Eval("EstateId")).Name %>' works , THANSK AMIRAM! ^^