# ASP.NET GridView TemplateField Call function(:int)

Tags: asp.net, function, gridview, int, call

My scenario is the following:

I have a GridView and made a class the represents a row in it.
I was expecting to show the properties and function's result of the class in the cells.

For this i'm using columns like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" text='<%# MatchesCount((Int32)1) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the class has the following function:

```
public class MatchesGridViewRow
{
...
    public string MatchesCount(int day) {...}
}
```

and I bind to the GridView like this:

```
GridView.DataSource = GetGridViewData(DateTime.Now.Month);
GridViewCalendar.DataBind();    

private List<MatchesGridViewRow> GetGridViewData(int month);
```

The error that I get is: 
CS0103: The name 'MatchesCount' doesnt exist in current context.

Isnt this the right way to call the method? If not how should i call it?
Thanks from now, looking forware to answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for change the method to static method

```
public static  string MatchesCount(int day) {...}
```

then call

```
'<%# MatchesGridViewRow.MatchesCount((Int32)1)%>'
```

Please check this same issue

[Accessing public static class files from .ASPX file using Eval("") from gridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492140/accessing-public-static-class-files-from-aspx-file-using-eval-from-gridview)

Comment: It wont work for my case because the result of the funcion depends of the current instance of the class MatchesGridViewRow.
I could make the function an array property. But how do I reference a position in the array in the .asxp page?

Comment: I made the function: 
 
    `public string MatchesCount(int day) {...}`

to
 
    `public String List<Match>[] { get; set; }`

After that I used this property in the .aspx page:
 
    `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("MatchesByDay[0].Count").ToString()=="0"?"":Eval("MatchesByDay[0].Count").ToString() %>' 
                        ToolTip='<%# Eval( "ToolTips[0]" ) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>`

Answer (score 1):

i check below code and it useful : 
i hope

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="type" ItemStyle-Width="200">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbtype" runat="server" Text='<%# GetDescrptionHumanType(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("HumanType"))) %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

   public  static string GetDescrptionHumanType(int val)
    {
       return  Utility.EnumEx.GetEnumDescription((HumanResourceType)val);

    }


   public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```